# Creating a data packet in c#

Tags: c#, string, hex

I want to create a data packet and write it to socket.
This packet starts with 'C0' hex value.
In php I easily can create it with this code:

```
$a = "\xC0";
```

now I want to create it in c#. How can do this?

Comment: you'll want to learn about byte[] and string conversions

Comment: The same I think, have you tried it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C#, strings are Unicode-encoded, so you shouldn't use them for binary data. Instead use a byte array.

To create a byte array starting with C0, do something like this:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[] { 0xC0, /* Other values */ };
```

If you have an existing string that you want to send, you can use `Encoding.ASCII` to convert it to the bytes you need.

Comment: @user1488521: Did this answer your question? If it did, please mark it as the answer, so people know the question has been answered.

Comment: Yes it is, but I can't do this because of my low reputation :(

Comment: You don't need any reputation to mark it answered. Click the check icon to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending bytes it's as easy as:

```
byte a = 0xC0;
```

If the packet contains text, you can start a string:

```
string a = "\xC0";
```

For more information on String Literals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx